# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 "start without debugging" and "start debugging" buttons are greyed out

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I just installed visual studio 22 on my MS windows 11 computer and I am trying to execute my first project.

I noticed that the "start without debugging" and "start debugging" buttons are greyed out. Surprissingly, the solution explorer is recording zero project, all though the name of the project I created is shown in the solution explorer.  Please see attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNgya.png)

I googled the problem, and saw several similiar complains but none of the provided solutions have worked for me. I have also uninstalled and installed VS 2022 several times, with now solution.

Please, I will be extremely grateful if someone can please help resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally seen an answer that worked for me. I figured others may find this answer useful.

Please check your System environment variables if there are two paths to dotnet.

C:\Program Files\dotnet

C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet

If so, please delete this one: C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet.

Then, restart your computer and check if the project can be created normally.

After the project is created successfully, the debug menu will display normally.

I got the answer from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1283801/microsoft-visual-studio-2022-run-without-debugging